# Images from google api are getting cached and I need to figure out how to remove them when the app closes

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-recyclerview

I built a `recyclerview` that gets data from `Google places api` and displays it. I didn't notice that the photos are being cached every time I open the app. According to google, that is illegal so I need to get rid of caching.

I initially thought it was because i used the Picasso library but i added code for that, and now I'm stuck. I get the data from google in a bitmap then send it through to the `recyclerview`. I pass it through a `URI` creator to be able to use it with the Picasso Library and I think that's where the photos get cached.

**The RecyclerView Adapter**

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VenueViewHolder venueViewHolder, int i) {
    Collections.sort(vIAL, (o1, o2) -> o1.getVenueName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getVenueName()));
    VenueItem currentItem = vIAL.get(i);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(getImageUri(context, currentItem.getVenueImage()))
            .fit()
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(venueViewHolder.vIV);
    venueViewHolder.vTV.setText(currentItem.getVenueName());
    Log.i(TAG, "The photo should have been on screen");
}
```

**The activity that I use to get info from Google**

```
 private void getClubs() {
    for (String club : clubs) {
        FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(club, placeFields);
        placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
            Place place = response.getPlace();

            PhotoMetadata photoMetadata = Objects.requireNonNull(place.getPhotoMetadatas()).get(0);
            //String attributions = photoMetadata.getAttributions();

            FetchPhotoRequest photoRequest = FetchPhotoRequest.builder(photoMetadata).setMaxHeight(1600).setMaxWidth(1600).build();
            placesClient.fetchPhoto(photoRequest).addOnSuccessListener((fetchPhotoResponse) -> {

                Bitmap bitmap = fetchPhotoResponse.getBitmap();

                vIL.add(new VenueItem( /*Photo*/bitmap, place.getName()));

                vRV.setLayoutManager(vLM);
                vRV.setAdapter(vAdapter);
            }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                    // Handle error with given status code.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            });

            Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getName());
        }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
            if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                // Handle error with given status code.
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My question is - how do I remove the cached photos from the phone when the app closes so it's not illegal, or how do I prevent them from being cached in the first place? Also, if possible - I used Picasso so that I could manipulate the images as they are displayed to the recyclerview and this is the only way I know how - is there a better way to present the pictures uniformally?

**EDIT:**
I am assuming that the `getImageUri` method is the culprit since adding code to the `Picasso` code does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Picasso automatically caches the loaded images, So that next time they will be loaded from the cache.

In order to skip image caching use this :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE) // prevents caching
            .into(imageView);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ,Nope it did not work. On the emulator it shows up in google photos and on my phone as well. Doesn't show up in my phone's gallery anymore though. Just google photos.