# Remove photos from device after android app closes

Tags: java, android, uri, picasso

**EDIT:**
I asked a similar question a day before and I wrote this post based on information I gathered since that question - 
[First Cache Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245472/images-from-google-api-are-getting-cached-and-i-need-to-figure-out-how-to-remove). I know they are similar but this question is more concise to avoid extra information. I also didn't want to delete that post since it was answered, even though the answer didn't suffice.

I use a recyclerview to show photos I get from `google places api`. I know that I am not allowed to legally cache photos outside of runtime. I didn't know that was happening until I randomly opened my phone's gallery to see a lot of copies of the photos I get from google.

My first guess was that my use of `Picasso` was the issue so I added code to fix it, 
 `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)`
finding these in `StackOverflow` was pretty simple, but this didn't fix anything except that now it seems to only download them once especially when I delete them. I believe I eliminated the possible issues and am outlining the last one in this question.

```
 private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VenueViewHolder venueViewHolder, int i) {
    Collections.sort(vIAL, (o1, o2) -> o1.getVenueName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getVenueName()));
    VenueItem currentItem = vIAL.get(i);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(getImageUri(context, currentItem.getVenueImage()))
            .fit()
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(venueViewHolder.vIV);
    venueViewHolder.vTV.setText(currentItem.getVenueName());
    Log.i(TAG, "The photo should have been on screen");
}
```

The `URI` method `getImageUri` is something I found as an answer to another problem I had, that I needed a `URI` to implement the `Picasso` library so that I can manipulate the photos before displaying them.

My question is - How do I remove the photos when the app closes?

**UPDATE:**
I changed my tactic to see what would happened and used `Glide`

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VenueViewHolder venueViewHolder, int i) {
    Collections.sort(vIAL, (o1, o2) -> o1.getVenueName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getVenueName()));
    VenueItem currentItem = vIAL.get(i);

     Glide.with(context)
            .load(currentItem.getVenueImage())
            .into(venueViewHolder.vIV);
    venueViewHolder.vTV.setText(currentItem.getVenueName());
}
```

and it gave a fatal Error

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 4344032)
```

This was one of the errors and it didn't occur the first time I ran this new code but it got worse the second and third time I ran it.

I shifted my code based on an answer I got early from @Padmini S but they used a url in the `load` part and I pass a bitmap because for the life of me I can't figure out how to get a `URL` from `Google Places API` instead of the code they provide in 
[Google Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/photos).

I'm relatively new to coding so this is me trying to piece together what I need to learn more. I'm just out of ideas of what to search for so I ask here, 
based on the new information I gathered from the answer, can I replace

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);`

in my code so that my photos don't get saved to my phone's photos?

**Final Update**
I ended up rewriting a lot of the code surrounding this and deleting this code. I ended up making an `arraylist` class to hold the array list for the duration of `runtime` and it let me remove most of the extra code I wrote out of ignorance.

Comment: Picasso doesn't add the images that it downloads to your phones photo album. Your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339624/how-to-ask-same-question-again-on-stack-overflow/339627 for asking the same Question again

Comment: thanks @DominikWuttke. I honestly didn't think about asking meta. I'll be more vigilent next time.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai, Does the MediaStore? I am not sure how to google the question properly

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know whether it'll solve your problem or not , but you are storing the images in device local storage here,

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {

    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);

}
```

I have never used google places api but usually apis will return you with an image url you can store that url in POJO class and display it directly in recyclerview row image view like I am doing in below code,

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.description.setText(links.get(i).getTitle());
        Glide.with(context).load(links.get(i).getImage_url()).into(viewHolder.image);
}
```

Comment: I'll look into it. That's what I narrowed it down to. I just didn't know where to go from there. Thank you